# How to view history of filled in Google forms?

Tags: google-forms

I have filled in many Google forms for an interview in last month so I want to  view details of what I have entered in those Google forms.

How can I get the history of all my filled in Google forms?

Answer (score 2):

To view what was entered you would need to have access to the Google Spreadsheet in which the form data is being saved to.

Alternatively there are extensions like [Lazarus : Form Recovery](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno?hl=en) which will save text you entered into the form previously, so that you can fill it using that data. Though this extension is more intended for recovering text in a form, such as if you accidentally leave the page and lose what you wrote you could recover it, though this may work for you.

OF course the extension would not allow you to get any old history from previous days, only from previous days starting from the date of using it.

Comment: The link is broken.