# I lost my response in Google Form after accidentally deleted the questions

Tags: google-forms

I created a google form this afternoon and there were lots of response that I received. And then I accidentally deleted all of the questions and I thought I can simply edited it back. when I edited it and add the same questions as before, I looked at the response and the number is still the same. But when I click button 'response' with the number of response, it shows 'no response yet' for each questions. Can I get the response back?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> **Yes you can get back deleted form Responses**

i know this is an old post but this answer is for anyone else looking for the same solution to a similar problem quite recently.

You might have some luck here- google has quite a good auto backup system when it comes to sheets

Login on your desktop browser for easier access

going by your screenshot -you still have 46 responses saved in a sheet someplace - if you want to know which sheet name click on that little green sheet logo on the right hand top corner of your google form on your phone - it will ask you if you want to change the location of your responses  "dont click anything " just make note of the sheet name that you see auto populated there.

Go to your google sheets in your google drive account & select that sheet that your form is linked to.

Click on "file" on the Menue

Click on  "Version History > See Version History "

let it load

on the right hand side of the page you will see the diffrent auto saves done by google sheets - it includes everything that was inputed onto the google sheets -all data including that of the form, since the last time you accessed it.

Just tick the option "see changes" you will see all the changes done across the sheet in each and every timestamped version.

when you found what you looking for  -clcik on "restore this version"

take note this will restore your sheet back to the version you have selected based on the date & time of that auto backup you selected

Answer (score 0):

The only way to recover the responses if you previously set your form to send the responses to a Google spreadsheet, if you didn't that before deleting the questions it's not posible to recover the responses.

Related

- [How to view history of filled in Google forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/46325/88163)
- [Edited Google Form while users were responding - how to recover initial responses?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102032/88163)
- [Is it possible to recover deleted responses from Google Forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/127697/88163)